# request.forward(request, response) get NullPointerException Error

Tags: jsp, servlets, netbeans, nullpointerexception, requestdispatcher

I get NullPOinterException Error when i run my processList.java servlet..please help

My Project explorer (I don't have enough reputation to show it directly...please click the link to see the image)

[my project explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EJJp.png)

processList.java servlet***I have check the universityList...it's not null

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
    universityList = new ArrayList<University>();
    String search = request.getParameter("searchName").toUpperCase();
    List h = session_univ.viewAllTrainer();
    Iterator i = h.iterator();
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        University univ = (University) (i.next());
        if (univ.getUnivName().contains(search)) {
            universityList.add(univ);
        }
    }
    request.setAttribute("universityList", universityList);
    RequestDispatcher req = request.getRequestDispatcher("searchResult.jsp");
    req.forward(request, response); // get NullPointerException Error
```

Error message

```
Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[processList]: Servlet.service() for servlet processList threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.jsp.searchResult_jsp._jspService(searchResult_jsp.java:70)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:411)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:875)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:739)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:575)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:546)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:428)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:378)
at business.controller.processList.processRequest(processList.java:71) // this line link me to req.forward(request, response)
at business.controller.processList.doGet(processList.java:86)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one( missed "/", i guess ) if you had included jsp file in the same package else go the respective package try to copy the path and paste there.

RequestDispatcher req = request.getRequestDispatcher("/searchResult.jsp");